# Mock a public method using Jmockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit, jmock

I have a class Handler.java

It has 2 public methods update(), fetch()

In the actual update() implementation I make a call to the public method fetch()

The fetch() in turn makes a call to a service.

So now I have to write a testUpdate() which would mock the public method call i.e. fetch()

Since its not static I tried creating another instance of the Handler.java as mocked i.e,

```
private Handler handler;

@Mocked
private Handler mockedHandler;
```

Now using the mockedHandler, I set the below code in my testUpdate()

```
new NonStrictExpectations(){
mockedHandler.fetch();
returns(response);
};

handler.update();
```

Now, I expect the mockedhandler to be used for calling the fetch() and the handler instance for calling the update().

But when I run the actual method call to update() is also mocked!!!

```
i.e. handler.update(); is not at all going to the update().
```

Help me mock the second public method which I call inside my update()

Thanks

Comment: Look at Spy http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds to me that you should be mocking the service class called from inside `Handler#fetch()`, rather than mocking the `fetch()` method.

Anyway, mocking *some* methods of a class while not mocking others is called *partial mocking*. In JMockit, you will normally use the `NonStrictExpectations(Object...)` constructor for that, like in the following example test:

```
@Test
public void handlerFetchesSomethingOnUpdate()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    new NonStrictExpectations(handler) {{
        handler.fetch(); result = response;
    }};

    handler.update();
}
```